# Powershell New-WebBinding Pipeline Issue with Name Property

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I'm encountering an issue with New-WebBinding when piping in an object. I have an object that defines 5 properties: Name, Protocol, Port, IPAddress and HostHeader (all 5 are supported in the New-WebBinding cmdlet as Accept Pipeline input: ValueByPropertyName). However, when you pipe in this object, it still requests a Name: to be submitted. Here is a quick test function if you'd like to duplicate the issue. If you hit enter at the prompt, it successfully processes the objects, adding the bindings. But the prompt itself breaks it as a non-interactive script.

I've tested this with both PS v3 and PS v4.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing this all correctly but wanted to make sure there wasn't something I might be overlooking. For now I'm just iterating through my object collection in a foreach loop which does not have this issue but would like to see if this is a bug I should report.

```
function Test-WebBinding{
   [CmdletBinding()]
   Param()

   $testBindingCol = @()

   $testBinding1 = New-Object System.Object
   $testBinding1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value 'Default Web Site'
   $testBinding1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Protocol -Value 'https'
   $testBinding1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Port -Value '4000'
   $testBinding1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value '*'
   $testBinding1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name HostHeader -Value 'Test4000'
   $testBindingCol += $testBinding1

   $testBinding2 = New-Object System.Object
   $testBinding2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value 'Default Web Site'
   $testBinding2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Protocol -Value 'http'
   $testBinding2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Port -Value '4001'
   $testBinding2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value '*'
   $testBinding2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name HostHeader -Value 'Test4001'
   $testBindingCol += $testBinding2

   $testBindingCol | New-WebBinding
}
```

Comment: Looking forward to seeing an answer to this. I also tried with variations of `PSObject` and `PSCustomObject` without success. Great question.

Comment: It doesn't appear Microsoft Connect is taking any bug reports for any version of Powershell at this time. So I'll just leave this a most likely bug and the only workaround is iterating through your objects in a foreach. I don't have version 5 yet, I'm wondering if it's resolved in the latest version.

Comment: This behaves the same in v5. I did disassemble `Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider` assembly where the `New-WebBinding` cmdlet resides and the properties we're interested in are correctly attributed with `[Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]`

Comment: It definitely bug. One workaround would be to change current location to some site (`cd IIS:\Sites\SomeSite`), it does not really matter to which.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PetSerAl is onto the right idea with his comment above:

> *One workaround would be to change current location to some site (`cd IIS:\Sites\SomeSite`), it does not really matter to which*

That does actually work, but why doesn't it work from the normal file system prompt?

To discover why `New-WebBinding` behaves this way I loaded the  `Microsoft.IIS.PowerShell.Provider` assembly containing this and other `WebAdministration` cmdlets into dotPeek. The assembly lives in the GAC so you tell dotPeek to "Open from GAC".

When loaded, the class we're interested in is called `NewWebBindingCommand`.

Upon a cursory inspection we can see that all of the parameter properties are decorated with the `[Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]` attribute so that's a good start, piping an array of objects with matching property names ought to work:

[image]

`NewWebBindingCommand` ultimately inherits from [`System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.cmdlet(v=vs.85).aspx) and in this instance is overriding the [`BeginProcessing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.cmdlet.beginprocessing(v=vs.85).aspx) method. If overridden, `BeginProcessing` is called by PowerShell and *"Provides a one-time, preprocessing functionality for the cmdlet."*

It is important to understand that a cmdlet's `BeginProcessing` override is called before any pipeline fed named parameters are processed and bound to the cmdlet's properties (see: [Cmdlet Processing Lifecycle (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714429(v=vs.85).aspx)) .

Our `New-WebBinding` cmdlet's implementation of `BeginProcessing` looks like:

```
protected override void BeginProcessing()
{
  base.BeginProcessing();
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.siteName))
    return;
  this.siteName = this.GetSiteName("Name");
}
```

`this.siteName` is the private member value for the `Name` property which would be bound to the `-Name` parameter. When we arrive at the `if(...)` statement above `this.siteName isn't yet bound (it's null) and so falls through to:

```
this.siteName = this.GetSiteName("Name");
```

The call to `GetSiteName()` calls up to the cmdlet's immediate base class `HelperCommand` which provides a number of "helper" methods that are useful to many different `WebAdministration` cmdlets.

`HelperCommand.GetSiteName(string prompt)` looks like this:

```
protected string GetSiteName(string prompt)
{
  PathInfo pathInfo = this.SessionState.PSVariable.Get("PWD").Value as PathInfo;
  if (pathInfo != null && pathInfo.Provider.Name.Equals("WebAdministration", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  {
    string[] strArray = pathInfo.Path.Split('\\');
    if (strArray.Length == 3 && strArray[1].Equals("sites", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      return strArray[2];
  }
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prompt))
    return this.PromptForParameter<string>(prompt);
  return (string) null;
}
```

For the purpose of learning about this issue I created my own PowerShell cmdlet (called the `Kevulator`, sorry) and pulled in the `New-WebBinding` cmdlet's `BeginProcessing()` code and the code from `New-WebBinding`'s base class helper method `GetSiteName()`.

Here's a screenshot of breaking inside `GetSiteName` in VS2015 when attached to a PowerShell session piping in your bindings to `New-Kevulator`:

[image]

The top arrow demonstrates that our `Name` property backed by `siteName` hasn't yet been bound and is still `null` (which as a mentioned above causes `GetSiteName` to be executed). We've also just stepped past a break point on this line:

```
PathInfo pathInfo = 
        this.SessionState.PSVariable.Get("PWD").Value as PathInfo;
```

...which determines what kind of path provider we're sitting at. In this case we're on a normal filesystem `C:\>` prompt so the provider name will be `FileSystem`. I've highlighted this with the second arrow.

If we `Import-Module WebAdministration` and `CD IIS:` then re-run and break again you can see that the path provider has changed to `WebAdministration` which is responsible for handling life inside `IIS:>` and beyond:

[image]

If the `pathInfo` name is not equal to `WebAdministration`, i.e. we're not at an `IIS:` prompt, then the code falls through and will prompt for the `Name` parameter at the command line, just as you've experienced.

If the `pathInfo` value *is* `WebAdministration` then one of two things will happen:

If the path is `IIS:` or `IIS:\Sites` the code falls through and issues a prompt for the `Name` parameter.

If the path is `IIS:\Sites\SomeSiteName` then `SomeSiteName` is returned and effectively becomes the `-Name` parameter value and we bail out from the `GetSiteName()` function back to `BeginProcessing`.

That last behaviour is useful because if your current path is say `IIS:\Sites\MySite` then you can pipe in an array of bindings for that site but without specifying the `Name` parameter. Alternatively if you do provide a `Name` property in your piped array of objects then these will override the default site name picked up from your `IIS:\Sites\MySite` context.

So, getting back to our code, once `BeginProcessing` has run its course our pipeline named parameters are now actually bound and then the `ProcessRecord` method is called, which is the meat and potatoes work that `New-WebBinding` has to perform.

**TLDR:**

`New-WebBinding` won't bind pipelined parameters unless you change your current working *directory* to an IIS website, e.g, `cd iis:\Sites\MySite`.

Comment: Excellent deconstruction and explanation. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: @Paolis you're welcome, it was an itch too good not to scratch :)